# Auto Size all columns to fit content

Tags: ag-grid

All my searches turned up for `sizeColumnsToFit` and `autoSizeColumns` which is not what I want.

My grids have many columns, so it scroll horizontal which is fine

But I cannot know in advance what would be the most space needed for the widest text in a column, so want the  grid to auto size all columns to accommodate for whatever is the longest line of text in the cell.

Can one do that?  (pretty much like have `nowrap` on a html table column, not that `ag-grid` wrap text, it just hide what is too long)

Comment: reading between the lines, i see that your use case may involve hidden columns (if the table has horizontal scroll). note that you cannot control the size of non-visible columns, unless you turn off virtualization (the grid's feature that renders only what's should be visible on screen)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply use **flex** instead of **width** in the column definitions. The grid will adjust automatically.

Comment: This one causes serious performance issues

Comment: @pantonis, can you reference a link from the docs to that?

Comment: This answer is wrong. The flex property does not set the width to fit the content, The flex property determines how much space a column should take up concerning the available space and other columns. It's a numeric value that represents the flex grow factor of the column.

Comment: @Normal RTFM https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/column-sizing/

Answer (score 48):

Grid Resizing:
https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-resizing/

`sizeColumnsToFit` - this tries to squeeze all the columns in the view - no horizontal scrolling

`autoSizeAllColumns` - this tries to size all columns to to fit the data - horizontal scrolling

```js
// If you need to resize specific columns 
var allColIds = params.columnApi.getAllColumns()
    .map(column => column.colId);
params.columnApi.autoSizeColumns(allColIds);

// If you want to resize all columns
params.columnApi.autoSizeAllColumns();
```

Comment: is there any way to set column width based content of cell ?

Comment: `params.columnApi.autoSizeColumns()` result not look good, got same width columns only, for whatever contents.

Comment: @Revansiddh - yes, that's exactly what `autoSizeColumns()` is for

Comment: also, this answer should definitely be accepted, @Nico

Comment: https://www.ag-grid.com/documentation/javascript/column-sizing/#resizing-columns-when-data-is-rendered <= worth to read this part to make sure that the method call is placed at the right event handler

Comment: @jackycflau yeah this is very important

Answer (score 14):

I passed through this and it took me some time to make it work the way I wanted to, by that I mean :

- Use all the available space
- Make each column take the width required to display its content correctly

Solution :

- Add the `width` parameter for each column (requires some manual tuning to set the right values)
- Call `gridApi.sizeColumnsToFit()` in the `onGridReady` which will resize to take the available space while making sure that columns having bigger width will take more space

```js
const gridOptions = {
 ...
 columnDefs: [
  {
    ...,
    width: 100
  },
  {
    ...,
    width: 50
  },
  ...
 ],
 ...
 onGridReady: (event) => event.api.sizeColumnsToFit(); 
};
```

Comment: The key for me was to call `gridApi.sizeColumnsToFit()` from `onGridReady`

Comment: The marked answer is incorrect and This one should be the accepted answer

Answer (score 2):

You can find a complete example for auto resizing all column.
[column-sizing](https://www.ag-grid.com/documentation/javascript/column-sizing/#resizing-example)

Simply call autoSizeColumns() function, all columns will be resized according to content.

```
gridColumnApi.autoSizeColumns(allColumnIds, skipHeader);
```

Answer (score 1):

This will help if anyone is looking to do this in python streamlit.

- Assuming gb is a AgGrid
- By setting `flex=1`, the columns will automatically adjust their width based on the content and available space within the grid
- If you have many columns and don't want to specify them one by one, you can use the `configure_default_column` method to set the default configuration for all columns.

```
gb = GridOptionsBuilder.from_dataframe(df_glb)
gb.configure_default_column(
    flex=1,
    minWidth=100,
    maxWidth=500,
    resizable=True,
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Please remove the **width** property in columnDefs array.

Comment: default width is hardcoded to be 200px